# Хранить изображение в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите, как праивильно cохранять изображение:  ввиде ссылки или записывать изображение в binary?

Comment: Смотря что с ним дальше делать. Если не предполагается обработка в самой БД, то лучше ссылку, что бы потом при необходимости так же ссылку и отдавать клиенту

Comment: [BinaryFilesInDB](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB)